# How to add C++ Library ( .a) file into C++/Java Hybrid Project

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

What I would like to do is to add C++ Library (.a) file into my C++ / Java Hybrid Project.
Actually, It's Android Project. I'm using C++ for native calls.

> The problem is I can't find any "Tool Settings" under "C++ Build/
>   Settings" to add ".a" library file into the project.

I think it is because of the nature or type of the Project. (As my project is Android Project.) Any points would be much obliged.

I have .h file and .a file. I can include ".h" file. But, when I invoke the method, the compiler said "no such method".

> I would like to add C++ Library (.a) file into Android Project. ( C++ / Java Hybrid Project.)

PS: I know Eclipse is poor in C++ Code Analysis. I have already turn off the Code Analysis in the project. So, It's obvious that the error is not C++ Code Analysis.

[image: C++ Build/ Settings]

Answer (score 1):

Check this link should help.

http://www.cmumobileapps.com/2011/08/31/compiling-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk-part-1/

This explains how to compile c/c++ source to produce static library, and then use this static library.